# Drawing on ImageView is too slow

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas, android-image

What I'm trying to achieve is simple `ImageEditor` , I have started with creating simple tool which is the `CropTool` as follow :

```
public class CropTool implements ITool {
    RectF top, right, bottom, left, crop;
    Paint fillPaint, cropPaint;

    public CropTool() {
        crop = new RectF();
        top = new RectF();
        right = new RectF();
        left = new RectF();
        bottom = new RectF();

        fillPaint = new Paint();
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        fillPaint.setARGB(150, 0, 0, 0);

        cropPaint = new Paint();
        cropPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        cropPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 99, 71);
    }

    @Override
    public void TouchStart(ImageView context, float x, float y) {
        crop.set(x, y, crop.right, crop.bottom);
    }

    @Override
    public void TouchMove(ImageView context, float x, float y) {
        crop.set(crop.left, crop.top, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void TouchUp(ImageView context, float x, float y) {
        crop.set(crop.left, crop.top, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void OnDraw(ImageView context, Canvas canvas) {
        if (crop.isEmpty())
            canvas.drawRect(0, 0, context.getWidth(), context.getHeight(), fillPaint);
        else {
            top.set(0, 0, context.getWidth(), crop.top);
            bottom.set(0, crop.bottom, context.getWidth(), context.getBottom());
            left.set(0, crop.top, crop.left, crop.bottom);
            right.set(crop.right, crop.top, context.getRight(), crop.bottom);

            canvas.drawRect(top, fillPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(bottom, fillPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(left, fillPaint);
            canvas.drawRect(right, fillPaint);

            canvas.drawRect(crop, cropPaint);
        }
    }
}
```

and the custom `ImageView`:

```
public class ImageEditView extends ImageView {
    private ITool currentTool;

    public ImageEditView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        currentTool = new CropTool();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (currentTool != null) currentTool.TouchStart(this, event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (currentTool != null) currentTool.TouchMove(this, event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                if (currentTool != null) currentTool.TouchUp(this, event.getX(), event.getY());
                break;
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (currentTool != null) currentTool.OnDraw(this, canvas);
    }
}
```

the problem is , the drawing is too slow , that it takes like 20secs to show the crop rectangle, how do I optimize that, or what am doing wrong here , and is my approach is correct or there is better way?

Comment: It works well on real device

Answer (score 0):

Emulators are painfully slow competing with your PC for resources (even on Xeon)!  Try it on a hardware device - phone or tablet.  Should work great.